# Finding a square root by division method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A gardener has 1000 plants. He wants to plant in such a way that the number of rows and columns remain same. Find the minimum number of plants he needed more for this.

Comment: Do you know what the division method is?  if not, shouldn't you try to find out?  And if you do, what happened when you tried to use it?

Comment: show some effort from your side

Answer (score 1):

The method of calculating square root that you are searching for is probably the one described in this video - http://youtu.be/UnshaiwljGY

Anyhow, coming to your question,

> sqrt(1000) = 31.6227
>   So, the next perfect square is 32<sup>2</sup> which is 1024
>   => The farmer needs 24 plants more.
>   This way the there will be 32 equal rows and columns of plants.

Comment: or... he needs no more plants if he plants 31x31